# Stairstepping piecharts with asp:chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, pie-chart

I was perusing the asp.net chart control's sample website, and came across something in the pie chart gallery. There was 3 pie charts, "stair stepped" on top of each other. I starting using this control for a financial services application, and would like to replicate this effect. It looks like this:

[3d Stair stepped Pie Chart http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/87a5caabca.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/87a5caabca.png)

I'd post some code on what I've accomplished so far, but I have no idea where to start with this. I'm guessing maybe I'd have to create the 3 charts, and offset their axes, am I off base here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 3 seperate series and assign them to seperate chart areas.

The chart areas need to stepped down the page using position.x and position.y

Other tricks include disabling the legend for the second and subsequent series.

To get the transparency affect you need to work at a data point level in the series. Note the Ownership data point is not transparent but the renting and leasing data points are.