# ASP.NET Chart Control - 3D Stacked Step pie

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

Does anybody know, how to make chart like this?

[image]

I have not found any way how to stack 3D pie charts. Stacking seems to me available only with Stacked Bar, 100% Stacked Bar, Stacked Column, and 100% Stacked Column.

This is example from ASP.NET Chart Control examples gallery, but this one is without any code behind ...

The only way how to at least get closer to this I've found is to create two series of data, each in its own chart area, but it's creating duplicated legend entries and with collectind small pie slices it changes color data entries. (Like that Ownership, Renting and Leasing labels are duplicated and with differenc colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a stair-stacked pie chart.

Your approach is basically correct - you need to create separate series and chart areas and position them on top of each other. You can then hide the legends for all but the first series.

There are a few examples if you google, see  for [**here**](http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/stair-stacked-pie-chart/) example.

Also see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523163/stairstepping-piecharts-with-aspchart-control) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at this: http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/stair-stacked-pie-chart/